# is 4k graphics / video card output resolution possible on a Mac Pro cylinder (with ubuntu)

Tags: mac

Before buying a new mac pro in the hope it will be usable as an ubuntu workstation at 4k resolution, I'd like to ask whether it's possible to run X at 4k on a new Mac Pro on either the D300, D500 or D700 Mac Pro models.

I am aware of the [MacPro](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacPro) document on help.ubuntu.com.  However, that document has a garbled structure, it's not clear which sections apply to the current Mac Pro and which to a previous generation, it doesn't mention video resolutions, and so does not come close to answering my questions.

Supplementary information that would useful includes whether 4k video can be achieved using free drivers, or whether proprietary drivers are required to reach that resolution.

3d performance is not important here.  This will be used as a 2d workstation running a traditional window manager.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, yes.

However, you will need to install the ATI graphics cards for this. Just use the "Proprietary Hardware" tool in the system settings panel. See [this part of the Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacPro#Video) for a bit more info.

When the drivers have installed and you have rebooted, set the resolution and enjoy!